# Using ipv6 addresses assigned to your VPS to provide native ipv6 access to your MacOSX

Tags: macos, ipv6, vps, openvz

Seems to be very common to be assigned several [ipv6 addressed when rent a VPS](http://lowendbox.com/blog/ramnode-15year-128mb-ovz-7month-512mb-kvm-and-more-in-4-locations/) but, what can you do with that?, why they provide them in a non aggregatable way?, can I use them to provide native ipv6 access to my remote laptop (MacOSX)?.

After a long unsuccessful search I decided to post the question and answer I found in hope to help others to take advantage of these addresses.

I hope it helps you to avoid a long waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here we go:

I posted a question [here](http://lowendbox.com/blog/ramnode-15year-128mb-ovz-7month-512mb-kvm-and-more-in-4-locations/#comment-197950) to get an official answer about why the VPS providers don't assign ipv6 addressed aggregatable.

Being said that, you can use them to provide native ipv6 access to remote devices connecting by means of a vpn technology to your VPS. In my case I'm going to expose how I did it using pptp in ubuntu 14.04 running in a VPS of ramnode and my MacOSX Maveriks laptop.

The steps followed were:

1. Set up some vpn approach ([in my case pptpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPTPServer)) and connet your laptop with it.
2. Remove the selected ipv6 address from venet0 in the vps (ifconfig venet0 inet6 del 2001:1800:2::370:e093/120)
3. Add the selected ipv6 substracting 1 to the last byte to the ppp0 interface (ifconfig ppp0 inet6 add 2001:1800:2::370:e092)
4. Configure the selected ipv6 address in the ppp0 interface of your laptop (ifconfig ppp0 inet6 2001:1800:2::370:e093 2001:1800:2::370:e092 prefixlen 128) and add a default route (route -n add -inet6 default 2001:1800:2::370:e092).

After that I'm able to connect from my laptop to any ipv6 address.
What you must be aware:

1. Don't disable the selected ipv6 address in the SolusVM Control Panel (it was my first mistake) as a way to reserve it
2. You must enable ipv6 in the vpn service, in my case (pptpd) just add "ipv6 ::1,::2" in /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
3. You can automatize it using  scripts in /etc/ppp/ip-v6{up|down}/ppp0 in Ubuntu and adding another one in /etc/ppp in MacOSX

```
    WST-0101:~ $ uname -a
    Darwin WST-0101.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun 3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

    WST-0101:~ $ ifconfig ppp0 
    ppp0: flags=8051 mtu 1396
    inet 10.1.2.4 --> 100.171.198.150 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 fe80::2a37:37ff:fe19:fe38%ppp0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9
    inet6 2001:1800:2::370:e093 --> 2001:1800:2::370:e092 prefixlen 128
    nd6 options=1

    WST-0101:~ $ ping6 -c 1 www.google.com
    PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2001:1800:2::370:e093 --> 2607:f8b0:400a:802::1012
    16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:400a:802::1012, icmp_seq=0 hlim=57 time=187.700 ms
```

Happy native ipv6 access!!!